# How do you grow a plant not in your hardiness zone?

Tags: greenhouse, cold-weather, hardiness-zone, climate

I understand that greenhouses are an option, this question is more towards being able to grow plants that normally prefer colder climates without having to spend loads of money on climate control. I am in central Florida. This question isn’t specific to any particular plant, but is aimed at growing plants that you can’t grow normally or via traditional greenhouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Growing plants in different climate zones can be a challenge. For people in warm climates. The first thing you need to do is make a plan. And research the climate your plant grows in likes. At our greenhouse, we use an aquarium and pump ice water through a trough that allows the plants we are growing to have the correct root temperatures.

Comment: I see, so to build on this I essentially have to create alternative methods of climate control for the plants ideal environment?

Comment: yes, unfortunately, plants are very fickle and you might need to build something to cater to their needs

Comment: that works for me, I was just stuck thinking of traditional climate control methods such as air conditioning which can be extremely expensive, but I would actually be able to use ice and such easily enough for it to be cost effective. Thank you for opening my mind to new ways of thinking about it!

Comment: Think of simpler methods for venus fly traps you want to avoid placing your plant directly in the refrigerator, which is often fatal,  instead know that the venus fly trap can also be put into hibernation with the changing of the light cycles

Comment: I see, so don’t over do it

Comment: It depends on the plant for the plants that cost over 100 dollars you better believe our greenhouse is going to make sure everything in its environment is simulated exactly. For example, ghost orchids are very hard and need a special enclosure built. To ensure best possible survival.

Comment: well, that makes sense, since you’d want to protect your investments accordingly. I’m less interested in decorative plants and more so towards edible plants

Comment: What plants are you looking to grow? You might not need to worry about seasonal changes if you are growing a tomato the most common reason for the plant to die is if you are not harvesting the fruit fast enough and the plant dies from exhaustion.

Comment: I’m mainly interested in avocados and strawberries as well as a few other ones I am finding as I go seed-wise. Essentially if I have it I want to grow it.

Comment: You have nothing to worry about with either of those

Comment: well the question is less specific to any particular plant and was more so a question of how to grow a plant outside of my hardiness zone that a greenhouse could not